# Send email in Android WITHOUT intent or GMail SMTP

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

So I'm either going to get crucified for this or it'll be accepted as the honest, researched question it is...

---

How does one go about sending an email (with an image attachment) in Android (I'm using Kotlin but I'm fine with Java) without:

- Intents - I don't want the user to see anything... It must just go in the background
- GMail - Every single example/piece of code/tutorial I can find always talks about using GMail's SMTP... I don't want that. I want to input my own SMTP details so the email doesn't have to come from a GMail account and look rather unprofessional.

---

Yeah I've tried researching but as stated above, I keep finding the easy route (GMail). I'm relatively new to Android dev (years on iOS) so if there's an API or something I'm missing, please let me know :)

Thanks

Comment: *I don't want the user to see anything*... Why?

Comment: Hi Mr Nosey :) because I need a signature the user will give emailed to a specific address. I can't use a server to do this (upload image and then send - the user wouldn't see that either) for certain reasons. I also don't want them to handle the emailing because the device this will be on will be handled by people which aren't always very tech savvy and the signatures can't afford to be lost.

Answer (score 0):

> Every single example/piece of code/tutorial I can find always talks about using GMail's SMTP... I don't want that. I want to input my own SMTP details so the email doesn't have to come from a GMail account and look rather unprofessional

Have your app contact your Web service, and have the Web service send the email on your behalf.

It's technically possible for you to use JavaMail and send SMTP directly from the client. This would require you to bake SMTP server information and user credentials into the app or to be able to download them from somewhere. Either will turn your SMTP server into a source of spam and related crap, as it will be easy for people to get at that information and use it to their own ends.

Comment: Hmm ok... Was trying to avoid the web service but you make a valid point about the spam issue... Thanks :)